# Twitter Bootstrap - make the well fullwidth

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently playing with bootstrap around and this is what I have created so far:
[Website](https://api.divshot.com/previews/8_gRps2xEf64GNmYIupg2mc4N6Ec0r3ihu97enst)

However,

I want that the well component of twitter bootstrap is closing with the well and the well should be full width.

So far I have created a container:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="well">Watch out:
    <a>Video!</a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

How to create the closing well?

Comment: what do you mean by "closing with the well"?

Comment: there should not be a gap between the well and the navigation and the hero bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div class="container-fluid">` has 60 px of top margin. Just decrease that to 40px and there will be no gap between `.well` and the navigation.

For `.hero-bar` to line up add `margin-top: -20px;` to `<div class="hero-unit">`

Comment: Thx for your answer. At the moment the page looks like that: https://api.divshot.com/previews/8_gRps2xEf64GNmYIupg2mc4N6Ec0r3ihu97enst However I do not want the gap around the well. How would you fix that?

Comment: same problem did you fix it?